# If a black hole with an event horizon of 1 cm were placed in the Sun core what would be the Suns' lifespan as a visible star?

Tags: black-holes, mass, event-horizon, estimation, sun

If a black hole with an event horizon of 1 cm were placed in the Sun core what would be the Suns' lifespan as a visible star? I want to get a visualisation of how much mass per second would be absorbed inside that BH.Should the cross section area be calculated,the growth of the event horizon with time which increases the cross section area of the inward flow?
When we get the surface area of the event horizon should that be divided by the area of a helium or hydrogen atom to get how much atoms in parallel transpass the event horizon. After that we should calculate how much atoms in series transpass the e.h. and as we know their speed being almost 300.000kmps and the length of a single atom we can figure out their number per second transpassing the cross section area with the surface of the He or H atom? Or it is much more complicated?

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/2743/2451 , https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/424929/2451 and links therein.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What would Happen if a Primordial Black Hole, with 5-10x time the mass of Earth, were to fall into our Sun?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/506845/)